# RabbitMQ Consumer always directly shutsdown (C#)

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

At The moment im learning how to work with the RabbitMQ.
Sending works. But Recieving doesn't  work. This is my code:

```
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = hostName };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,
                             durable: false,
                             exclusive: false,
                             autoDelete: false,
                             arguments: null);
            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved: {0}", message);
            };
            consumer.Shutdown += (o, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error with RabbitMQ: {0}", e.Cause);
                createConnection(hostName, queueName);
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
        }
```

This is copied from the Tutorial. If I start the Application, consumer.Shutdown is directly called and I get:

```
    {AMQP close-reason, initiated by Application, code=200, text="Goodbye", classId=0, methodId=0, cause=}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is it a console app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`channel.BasicConsume` is non-blocking call, which means it will return immediately. What happens next in your example is your channel and connection are getting disposed (because of `using` statement), and so you see immediate shutdown. In the example you copied this code from, there is `Console.ReadLine` statement right after `channel.BasicConsume`. This prevents channel and connection from disposing until user press key in console.

Comment: Wow, so easy 
but how can I prevent the connection from disposing without Console.ReadLine?

Comment: Well you dispose it yourself in your example. Just don't use "using" block. Instead, dispose it explicitly when needed (for example, if that is asp.net application - dispose it on application shutdown).

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm new to c# and RabbitMQ and will never do this again :)