# RABBITMQ C# Works nice on console but not for a service

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, rabbitmq

I learn how to consume messages from RabbitMQ through the https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html or the Tutorial on the same website.

It works nice on console application! 
What i'm doing?
I just consume the message and i publish a return so the message from queue is finished, removed. Its OK!
Now im trying to make a multi-threading windows service to do this, because i need a better and faster way to consume a lot of messages from a queue.

I find out so difficult to find information to create a service so i decided to ask you if you can help-me

first of all there is a strange situation that i can't understand. Lets see a basic structure for consume messages bellow:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
    using(var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using(var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "task_queue",durable: true,exclusive: false,autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

        channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);

        Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages.");

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);

            int dots = message.Split('.').Length - 1;
            Thread.Sleep(dots * 1000);

            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Done");

            channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
        };
        channel.BasicConsume(queue: "task_queue",autoAck: false,consumer: consumer);

        Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
    =>> Console.ReadLine(); <<=
    }
}
```

See the "Console.ReadLine();"? On console application, this command prevents from connection and channel from disposing! Without this RabbitMQ returns a error message! (code=200, text="Goodbye")! But its ok, i wont remove this on console application! But how can i use this on Windows service?

So i find a solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054079/rabbitmq-consumer-always-directly-shutsdown-c) and i could make a service to consume messages but it works well only for 1 or 2 messages. I have threads to consume messages but if there are a lot of messages on queue, the consumers (threads) try to consume the same message, or dont receive any message, resulting in errors. I've tried different ways to solve this but the results are the same.
I'd like to make a service that can work well as the console application but faster with a multi threading way.

What i have to do is:
1 - Consume the message
2 - Execute something using the data from the message
3 - Publish a return to a queue about that message so the message is finished.

MY CODE:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public static ConnectionFactory factory;
    public static string fila = "QUEUE";
    public static int threads = 0;
    private Thread executeThread;


    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        {
            System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("amqp://ARABBITMQNURL:8080");
            factory.Uri = uri;
        };

        try
        {
            executeThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(start));
            executeThread.Start();
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\iviservicetesterabbit.txt", "\r\n starting");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\iviservicetesterabbit.txt", "\r\n starting error: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private static void start()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            ThreadStart go = new ThreadStart(ServerRPC);
            Thread T = new Thread(go);
            T.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Ivi client stopped", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
    }

    private static void ServerRPC()
    {
        threads++;

        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\iviservicetesterabbit.txt", "\r\n"+ threads);

        IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        IModel channel = connection.CreateModel();

        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: fila, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
        channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

        ConsumoMSG.Consumer(fila, consumer, channel, connection);

        channel.BasicConsume(queue: fila, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);

    }

}

public static void Consumer(string fila, EventingBasicConsumer consumer, IModel channel, IConnection connection)
    {
        channel.BasicConsume(queue: fila, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);

        consumer.Received += (ch, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body;
            var props = ea.BasicProperties;
            var replyProps = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
            replyProps.CorrelationId = props.CorrelationId;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\iviservicetesterabbit.txt", "\r\n " + message);

                Execute.Powershell(); //this start a ps1 that sleep for 5 sec.

                var response = "{\"code\":\"500\",\"response\":\"PowershellReturn\"}";

                var responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);

                try
                {
                    channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: props.ReplyTo, basicProperties: replyProps, body: responseBytes);
                    channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
                    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\iviservicetesterabbit.txt", "\r\n PUBLISH OK!! routingKey: " + props.ReplyTo + "basicProperties: " + replyProps);
                Service1.threads--;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\iviservicetesterabbit.txt", "\r\n ERROR PUBLISH: " + e.Message);
                    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\iviservicetesterabbit.txt", "\r\n ERROR PUBLISH routingKey: " + props.ReplyTo + "basicProperties: " + replyProps);
                }
            channel.Close();
            connection.Close();

        };
    }
}
```

May i have another way to do this? What im doing wrong?

Thankyou!

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to: In OnStart create the connection/channel and a bunch of workers, waiting for incoming messages. Then register the Receive handler which will decode messages and have them processed by the workers. Those in turn will process and publish their results. OnStop should stop the channel, (maybe) wait for the workers to run dry, then dispose of the channel/connection ...

Comment: I use TopShelf (http://topshelf-project.com) to configure a windows service and the RabbitMq consumer works fine. I'll provide a running example later

Answer (score 0):

This code works as a windows service. It uses TopShelf (http://topshelf-project.com).

Please read the comment in the second line.

```
class Program
    {
        //I declare as class fields so they are not garbage collected and the consumer can stay alive
        private EventingBasicConsumer _consumer;
        private IModel _channel;
        private IConnection _connection;

        public bool Stop()
        {
            _channel.Dispose();
            _connection.Dispose();
            return true;
        }

        public bool Start()
        {

            var factory = new ConnectionFactory() {HostName = "localhost"};
            _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            _channel = _connection.CreateModel();

            _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                durable: false,
                exclusive: false,
                autoDelete: false,
                arguments: null);

            _consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
            _consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

            };
            _channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello",
                autoAck: true,
                consumer: _consumer);

            return true;
        }


        public static void Main()
        {

            var rc = HostFactory.Run(x => //1
            {
                x.Service<Program>(s => //2
                {
                    s.ConstructUsing(name => new Program()); //3
                    s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start()); //4
                    s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop()); //5
                });
                x.RunAsLocalSystem(); //6

                x.SetDescription("Sample Topshelf Host"); //7
                x.SetDisplayName("Stuff"); //8
                x.SetServiceName("Stuff"); //9
            }); //10

            var exitCode = (int) Convert.ChangeType(rc, rc.GetTypeCode()); //11
            Environment.ExitCode = exitCode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes i know TopShelf  and i tried before but that's is not the point! the service works fine! The main problem is to keep the connection alive from Channel to work as the Console way. Tks

Comment: Yes, my code addresses the problem of the connection being kept alive too, does it work for you?  I used TopShelf just because it was easier for me to test it.

Comment: I lost some time to answer you, would you be so kind to tell me whether your problem it's solved now?

Comment: Oh sorry, im glad you help-me. Well...as i said, TopShelf did not solve my problem before i'll try again and i will post the code here! Let's see...