# .NET 6 Console Application, RabbitMQ consuming doesn't work when it's out of the Program.cs file

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I'm trying to create a consumer on console application app according to this example:
https://rabbitmq-website.pages.dev/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet

I notice that when I shift the code outside the program.cs file to different class, it's not working, The code is exactly the same

The code in my program.cs file

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "rpc_queue",
                     durable: false,
                     exclusive: false,
                     autoDelete: false,
                     arguments: null);
channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
channel.BasicConsume(queue: "rpc_queue",
                     autoAck: false,
                     consumer: consumer);

consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    string response = string.Empty;

    var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
    var props = ea.BasicProperties;
    var replyProps = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
    replyProps.CorrelationId = props.CorrelationId;

    try
    {
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        Console.WriteLine($"Consumer: message from clien => {message}");
        response = "This message is from Consumer";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response = string.Empty;
    }
    finally
    {
        var responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
        channel.BasicPublish(exchange: string.Empty,
                             routingKey: props.ReplyTo,
                             basicProperties: replyProps,
                             body: responseBytes);
        channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
    }
};
Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

And the code in some other class is exactly the same

```
public class RcpServer
{
 public void Start()
 {
  [Same code as above without the 2 last lines (Console.read/Console.write)]
 }
}
```

Then in program.cs file I have the following code

```
RcpServer rcpServer = new RcpServer();
rcpServer.Start();
Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

But this code doens't work,

After some searching I found this post
[RABBITMQ C# Works nice on console but not for a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413328/rabbitmq-c-sharp-works-nice-on-console-but-not-for-a-service) but unfortunately couldn't solved it :(

What I need is to run the consumer as "background" service.
Please help,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .net worker service to consume messages [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that when you move the code into a method of another class (RcpServer.Start() in your case), you must ensure that the connection and channel remain open for as long as you want to consume messages. In your Program.cs, you are encountering a scope issue where the connection and channel are being disposed of immediately after the Start() method finish execution because they are wrapped in using statements, which automatically dispose of them once the execution leaves the scope of the using block.

The solution is to "capture" the `IConnection` and `IModel` and keeping them opened as long as needed by handle the scope of it parent class `RpcServer`:

```
public class RpcServer : IDisposable
{
    private IConnection connection;
    private IModel channel;

    public void Start()
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
        connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        channel = connection.CreateModel();

        // Rest of code   
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (channel != null)
        {
            channel.Close();
            channel.Dispose();
        }
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is quick usage solution that keeps them alive (by not disposing their class parent) until the user press a button:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (RpcServer rpcServer = new RpcServer())
    {
        rpcServer.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Later on you read about how to inject it properly via the dependency injection container and long running services.